# Changing website user-interface dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I'm currently developing a medical application that deals with artificial respiration ( important project for COVID-19 especially ), the application works fine but I have a problem based on design selection.

In medical application world, you can find a ton of brands of artificial respiration machines, and I'd like my application to be able to simulate the look that each machines have.

For example :

Here's an artifical repirator UI => https://www.swissinfo.ch/image/45620400/3x2/640/426/99f9e3cd33cb41fcaabfb8d48daffa69/Ky/hamilton.jpg

And here's another one =>https://afiris.si/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/SV-300-3-1-e1522149651805.jpg

They both have the same functions and buttons but not the same design, hence I'd like to know if there is a way to make the user be able to select the UI of the website with a dropdown list ( it can be a plugin, a code, HTML, CSS, JS, anything ! )

Thank you for your reponses ! =)

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a library such as Angular, React, Knockout or Vue.

They will allow you to write the functionality in pure JavaScript (with no direct reference to the DOM) and then you can design HTML with elements which bind onto exposed fields in the JavaScript.

Thus you can switch to different user interfaces without changing the underlying functionality.

Comment: I'll take a look at those libraries ! Thank you a lot ! =)